# Want to create custom option in custom post type

Tags: wordpress

I am working on product and  recipes wordpress website. Here admin can add different options of a product like, product format availability, Nutrition Information and Where to buy. Here i have attached the following screenshot.
[image]

Now you can see that admin can add another options in the previous options like Pre-Sliced, Salami chub etc.

How can i get this specific functionality. Via Plugin or custom functionality?
If Custom functionality then which flow should follow.

Answer (score 0):

follow : https://docs.woothemes.com/document/variable-product/

Assuming that you are developing with woocommerce plugin.

```
                                                                          B.
```

Comment: No i am not using woocommerce plugin, becuse my website is not shopping site.

Comment: Then, why don't you use custom post type?

Comment: Ya i know but how will flow work. Can you explain step by step.